# Query elements of a list inside a dictionary for generic type

Tags: c#, linq

I have a dictionary with a key and values as a list with my class `StructureData`.

```
private readonly Dictionary<IntBound, List<StructureData>> structuresDataCollection;
```

We can get `RoadStructureData` (which inherits `StructureData`) like this:

```
public IEnumerable<RoadStructureData> GetRoadDataWithin(IntBound position)
{
    return (IEnumerable<RoadStructureData>)structuresDataCollection.Where(s => s.Key.Intersects(position)).Where(s => s.Value.OfType<RoadStructureData>().Any()).Select(s => s.Value);
}
```

But I need to write a more generic method to get `StructureData` for a specified child type for a selected `IntBound`.

I suppose it could look like this:

```
public IEnumerable<StructureData> GetDataWithinOfType(IntBound position, Type requiredType)
{
    return structuresDataCollection.Where(s => s.Key.Intersects(position)).Where(s => s.Value.OfType<requiredType>().Any()).Select(s => s.Value);
}
```

But we can't use a `Type` variable in the `OfType<Type>()` method. How to rewrite this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use generics:

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetRoadDataWithin<T>(IntBound position)
    where T : StructureData
    => structuresDataCollection
        .Where(s => s.Key.Intersects(position))
        .Where(s => s.Value.OfType<T>().Any())
        .Select(s => s.Value.OfType<T>());
```

The `OfType<T>` will return an `IEnumerable<T>`, so you don't need the extra cast (i.e `OfType<RoadStructureData>` will return an `IEnumerable<RoadStructureData>`)

usage:

```
var roadStructureData = GetRoadDataWithin<RoadStructureData>(position);
```

BTW, note that this code (like the code you wrote) assumes that each list can only have one specific type - so if for instance you have both `X` and `Y` types inheriting `StructureData`, each list can hold only `X` or only `Y`, you can't have a list where some items will be `X` and others `Y`.